# Is the increase in Type I errors due to multi-sample t-tests overstated?

Tags: t-test, multiple-comparisons, type-i-and-ii-errors

To illustrate, let's say you want to compare the means of 3 samples with t-tests. You would then have to run 3 tests to compare the means of each possible combination of samples. The explanations I have read thus far as to why this is not preferable all give something along the lines of "if the significance of each test is .05 then the probability of a type I error after all tests have been conducted is 1-.95^3 = 14.26%, far greater than the desired 5%" It seems to me though that it would make a lot more sense to use the p-values for this calculation and only apply the significance level at the end. For example, if the p-values for each test are .006, .019, and .021, we could perform the calculation 1-(1-.006)(1-.019)(1-.021) to get a final value of .045. If we apply the significance level to the result of this calculation, we can say that .045 is less than .05 and therefore state with an acceptable level of confidence that the samples come from different populations. What am I missing here?

Comment: You seem to want to combine 3 $t$ tests into one omnibus test for the null hypothesis that there are no differences. If you want to test that null, use the Anova $F$ test. Otherwise, you want to look at those p values individually, to make an inference about each comparison - not combine them.

Comment: In addition, the pairwise comparisons are NOT independent of one another, so that is not the correct calculation.

Comment: In addition to rvl's valid comments, your approach breaks down when p = 1.0.

Comment: Why are the comparisons not independent?

Comment: @rvl forgot to tag you in the last comment but I would really appreciate an understanding of why the comparisons are not independent

Comment: Because each mean is involved in more than one comparison. For example, A - B and A - C both involve A.